# JSON to GSON Objects

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am new to GSON and thus far have been successfully using it in my project.  This JSON has been problematic for me...

```
 {
        "status": "6000",
        "action": "getProducts",
        "categories": {
            "type1": [
                {
                    "name": "name1",
                    "subtitle": "subtitle1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "name2",
                    "subtitle": "subtitle2"
                }
            ],
            "type2": [
                {
                    "name": "name3",
                    "subtitle": "name3"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

What's throwing me off is that I don't want to have to know the names "type1", "type2", etc.  They will be used to dynamically populate a list view.  What should my GSON objects looks like? or should my JSON be refactored?  I have full control over the backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
...
private Map<String, YourObject[]> categories;
...
```

or

```
...
private Map<String, List<YourObject>> categories;
...
```

and then you would call `categories.keySet()` to get set of `type1, type2, ...`